# Flutter connecting to multiple BLE devices Synchronously

Tags: asynchronous, dart, async-await, flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm using flutter to work on an bluetooth low energy app, via the flutterBlue library, in which we are potentially connecting to multiple peripherals at the same time.
I am able to connect to multiple peripherals if I connect to them individually and send commands to all of them simultaneously.
For state management, my BluetoothHelper is the Model for my ScopedModel.

```
class BluetoothHelper extends Model {

  bool isProcessing = false; 
  int val = 0;

  FlutterBlue flutterBlue = FlutterBlue.instance; //bluetooth library instance

  StreamSubscription scanSubscription;
  Map<DeviceIdentifier, ScanResult> scanResults = new Map();

  /// State
  StreamSubscription stateSubscription;
  BluetoothState state = BluetoothState.unknown;

  /// Device
  List<BluetoothDevice> devicesList = new List(); //todo

  bool get isConnected => (deviceList.size != 0);
  StreamSubscription deviceConnection;
  StreamSubscription deviceStateSubscription;
  List<BluetoothService> services = new List();
  Map<Guid, StreamSubscription> valueChangedSubscriptions = {};
  BluetoothDeviceState deviceState = BluetoothDeviceState.disconnected;

  Future startScan(String uuid) async {
    isProcessing = true;
    if (val == 0) {
      Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 25), () => scanAndConnect(uuid));
      val++;
    } else {
      Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 4), () => scanAndConnect(uuid));
    }
  }

  scanAndConnect(String uuid){
    scanSubscription =
        flutterBlue.scan(timeout: const Duration(seconds: 120), withServices: [
          //new Guid('FB755D40-8DE5-481E-A369-21C0B3F39664')]
        ]).listen((scanResult) {
          if (scanResult.device.id.toString() == uuid) {
            scanResults[scanResult.device.id] = scanResult;

            print("found! Attempting to connect" + scanResult.device.id.toString());
            device = scanResult.device;

            //connect(device);
            connect(device);
          }
        }, onDone: stopScan);
  }

  Future connect(BluetoothDevice d) {

    deviceConnection = flutterBlue.connect(d).listen(
          null,
        );

    deviceStateSubscription = d.onStateChanged().listen((s) {
      if (s == BluetoothDeviceState.connected) {
        stopScan();
        d.discoverServices().then((s) {
          print("connected to ${device.id.toString()}");
          services = s;
          services.forEach((service) {
            var characteristics = service.characteristics;
            for (BluetoothCharacteristic c in characteristics) {
              if (c.uuid.toString() == '') {//we look for the uuid we want to write to
                String handshakeValue ; //value is initiliazed here in code
                List<int> bytes = utf8.encode(handshakeValue);
                d.writeCharacteristic(c, bytes,
                    type: CharacteristicWriteType.withResponse);
                     devicesList.add(d);
              }
            }
          });
        });
      }
    });

  }
}
```

I am trying to loop throw all peripheral Unique Identifier (UID) and then have them connect one after the other programmatically.

This wasnt working out great. It would always end up connecting to the very last peripheral. Seems like the flutterblue instance can only scan for one uid at a time, and if it receives another request, it immediately drops the last request and moves to the new one.

I applied this same logic to the connection of an individual peripheral logic where I'd tap one peripheral and the second immediately and it'd connect to the second one. (I'm not currently blocking the UI or anything while the connection process takes place)
I need to wait till the first peripheral is connected before moving onto the next one.

The code above is the only way I've gotten my peripherals but there are huge problems with this code. It can currently only connect to 2 devices. It's using delays instead of callbacks to achieve connection by giving enough time for the scan and connect to happen before moving onto the second peripheral.

My first instinct was to make the convert the startScan and connect methods into async methods but this isnt working out well as I'd hope.

{await connect(device); } => gives "The built in Identifier "await" cant be used as a type. I could just be setting up the asyncs incorrectly.

I have looked around for alternatives and I've come upon Completers and Isolates. I'm not sure how relevant that might be.

UI SIDE :

I have the following method set for the ontap of a button wrapped within a scoped model descendant. This is going to reliably load peripheralUIDs list with a few uids and then connect to them one after the other.

```
connectAllPeripherals(BluetoothHelper model, List<String> peripheralUIDs) {
    for(var uuid in peripheralUIDs) { //list of strings containing the uuids for the peripherals I want to connect to
      model.startScan(uuid);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this point is still an issue.

Assuming your issue hasn't since been fixed. I think the issue you have is trying to maintain the connections within Flutter (rather than just connecting multiple devices and letting Flutter_Blue/the hardware manage the connections).

I've got it happily connecting to multiple devices; after you've setup the instance maintaining a list of multiple device attributes.

i.e. I made a ble-device class which contained each of the following:

```
StreamSubscription deviceConnection;
StreamSubscription deviceStateSubscription;
List<BluetoothService> services = new List();
Map<Guid, StreamSubscription> valueChangedSubscriptions = {};
BluetoothDeviceState deviceState = BluetoothDeviceState.disconnected;
```

Maintaining a LinkedHashMap with a new object initialised from the class above for each device connected works nicely.

Other than that - Flutter_Blue will only allow 1 concurrent request call at a time (like reading a characteristic), but you can stack them pretty easily with

```
 await
```

with the above, I'm able to poll multiple devices within a few milliseconds of each other.

Don't know if that helps - but with any luck, someone also coming across my problem will hit this and save some time.

Comment: So keeping multiple devices connected was not an issue. I just keep a list of devices  and sending commands to them works great! Issue was programmatically connecting to one after the other. Why it was an issue was I was trying to wait for a method that returns future but that future was supposed to come from within a stream (any ideas on how I can solve that as that would still be helpful?) but I can now connect to as many devices as I want by using a queue and it works pretty well.

Comment: I guess you trying to connect to a pretty large number of devices? (connecting to 6 or so shouldn't be an issue when maintaining the connection - you should only need to programmatically connect/disconnect for very large numbers).
Can you explain the future issue further - is it still originating from the "{await connect(device); } => " issue you mentioned above?